# How do I access the text input value in selenium webdriver mocha tests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

Need help testing user interactions with mocha selenium webdriver. No idea where to find what the correct method is to get value of text input. Tried various variations on getAttribute(), getText etc. Get the same error:

```
TypeError: Object [object object] has no method 'getElementText'
```

Here is my code:

```
var assert = require('assert'),
    fs = require('fs');

var webdriver = require('../node_modules/selenium-webdriver'),
    test = require('../node_modules/selenium-webdriver/testing'),
    remote = require('../node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote');


test.describe('Google Search', function() {
  var driver;

  this.timeout(60000);

  test.before(function() {
    driver = new webdriver.Builder().
        withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
        build();
  });

  test.it('should append query to title', function() {

    //setTimeout(done, 60000);

    driver.get('http://localhost:8080/devanagariTextField/index.html');

    driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('textbox')).sendKeys('gaa');
    //driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('btnG')).click();
    driver.wait(function() {
      return driver.getElementText('value').then(function(text) {
        console.log('TEXT: ' + text)
        return 'गा' === text;
      });
    }, 1000);
  });

  //test.after(function() { driver.quit(); });
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to perform the getText/getAttribute call on the element, not the driver object

```
var myTextBox = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('textbox'));
myTextBox.sendKeys('gaa');

//You will probably want to use getAttribute()
var elementContent = myTextBox.getText();
var elementValue = myTextBox.getAttribute("value");
```

Comment: `getAttribute("value")` is *really* how you do this?! That doesn't make any sense. There's a big difference between the `value` attribute of an `input` element and its `value` property. Does Selenium do the horrible thing jQuery does and conflate them?

Comment: my input inspecting with browser was `<input name="foo" value="bar">` and your advice worked like a charm `await driver.findElement(By.css("input[name='foo']")).getAttribute("value")`

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me in the end. I needed to use the `.then()` function after the `sendKeys()` call and then return the value attribute at that point. Steve's answer was helpful but I came to this by playing around with an example set up on git hub called [selenium-mocha-chai-saucelabs](https://github.com/jamsyoung/selenium-mocha-chai-saucelabs).

```
    describe('textbox value', function (done) {
    it('is expected to equal ka when keys ka are sent', function (done) {
        driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id("textbox"))
          .sendKeys("ka")
          .then(function(){
            return driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id("textbox")).getAttribute("value");
          })
          .then(function (value) {
              expect(value).to.equal('ka');
              done();
          });
    });
});
```

Comment: Being an OO guy this syntax seems insane to me, so I'm glad you got it working! Thanks for the vote, happy to help